# Is $f(x,y)=0~ \mu$-a.e.?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb{R_{2}^{+}}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{x}\int\limits_{0}^{y}f(u,v)\,\mu(du,dv)=0\qquad\forall \,x,y>0.
\end{equation}

Here, $\mu$ is the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Is it then true that $f= 0$ [$\mu$-a.e]? If not, is there any counterexample?

Any hints to approach the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that this follows by the one-dimensional case (i.e. if $\int_0^x f(x) dx =0$ for all $x$, then $f=0$ a.e.) and by Fubini-Tonelli.

Comment: I don't see how this should work… on the one hand you need integrability of f or at least non-negativity for Fubini-Tonelli… none of that is given here.

Comment: @Gono I second your opinion. Also, in the one-dimensional case, if $f$ is any measurable function (not necessarily integrable as pointed out by Gono in the above comment). then does it necessarily follow that if $\int_0^x f(x) dx =0$ for all $x$, then $f=0$ a.e.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $f=f_1-f_2$ with $f_1\ge0$ and $f_2\ge0$. Define measures $\mu_i$ by
$$ \mu_i(E)=\int_E f_i \,d\mu. $$
From the assumption, it immediately follows that $\mu_1(R)=\mu_2(R)$ for any rectangle $R=(a,b)\times(c,d)$. A uniqueness theorem on the extension of measures implies that $\mu_1=\mu_2$ on Borel sets. Since they are both absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure, they agree on the Lebesgue sigma-algebra. It is now easy to show that $f_1=f_2$ a.e., and therefore $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: > From the assumption, it immediately follows that $\mu_1(R)=\mu_2(R)$


Why should that follow "immediately? Could you explain that a bit more detailed? I doubt that…

Comment: @Gono Well, it *does* follow immediately for $R=(0,x)\times(0,y)$. And then you can use $\mu_i\bigl((a,b)\times(c,d)\bigl)=\mu_i\bigl((0,b)\times(0,d)\bigl)-\mu_i\bigl((0,b)\times(0,c)\bigl)-\mu_i\bigl((0,a)\times(0,d)\bigl)+\mu_i\bigl((0,a)\times(0,c)\bigl)$ (begin a little sloppy with the end points of the intervals, since the measure is a.c. wrt Lebesgue measure).

Comment: Yeah… I actually figgure out for myself that the notation of the question was confusing me… there is written $$\int_0^x\int_0^y$$ but $\mu$ shell be the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Your answer is totally right because $f$ ofc then is integrable on R (and so is $|f|, f^+,f^-$ by assumption). I had in mind that the given assumption was $$\int_0^x\int_0^y f(u,v) \mu(du) \mu(dv)$$ with $\mu$ given as 1-dim-lebesgue measure. Then you can only conclude that $f(u,\cdot)$ is (1-dim) integrable for each  fixed $v$ and your argumentation does not work.
Thx for your comment.